# RequestTracker and Mason destroying my class over and over again

Tags: perl, mason, rt

I'm hacking on Request Tracker, which is written in perl and uses Mason
for the web interface.  I'm trying to make a customized page, that involves an autohandler, an html page, and pulls in some methods in other comps.  I have a simple class that I want to use to track a few things that I need for my parts of the interface. Right now all it
tracks is a database handle.

```
package RTx::FooBar::Web;

use strict;
use warnings;

use RTx::FooBar::Handle;

sub new
{
        my $proto = shift;

        $RT::Logger->debug("creating new");

        my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
        my $self = {};
        bless( $self, $class);

        my $handle = RTx::FooBar::Handle->new();
        $handle->Connect();
        $self->{cfHandle} = $handle;
        return $self;
}

sub DESTROY {
        my $self = shift;
        $RT::Logger->debug("destroy");

        delete $self->{cfHandle};
}

sub CFHandle
{
        my $self = shift;

        return $self->{cfHandle};
}

1;
```

I tried sticking that into the session so I could use it wherever I needed
it in the web interface.  So I try to use it in one web page - the autohandler does:

```
% $m->call_next; 

<%INIT>
$RT::Logger->debug("my autohandler");
use RTx::FooBar::Web;
$session{cfWeb} ||= RTx::FooBar::Web->new();
</%INIT>
```

The thing that's bugging me right now (other than the fact that it's not
working) is that the logging in the "new" method prints out once, but the
logging in the DESTROY method prints out 56 times.  And each time, the
debug in RTx::FooBar::Handle->DESTROY prints out as well, indicating that
$self->{cfHandle} wasn't removed.  Can anybody suggest why this might be
happening?  Is it because session is a tied hash?

****Update****  I'm no longer using $session, and it's STILL destroying my handle 56 times after creating it once.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here - `$session` is re-creating your objects from an externalized version (perhaps via Storable or the like).  So it gets the object back without calling `new` so no logging.  Not sure why it would be getting destroyed every time tho.

It looks like `$session` is in fact a tied hash, to an `Apache::Session` or something implementing the same interface (the docs talk about db backing for sessions).

If you want to have a global persistent object (i.e., not tied to a single request) then give it a fully-qualified name, e.g., `$RTx::FooBar::Web::TheObject ||= RTx::FooBar::Web->new();` or use something like `Cache::MemoryCache`.  Alternately, set up your own global variable in the `MasonAllowGlobals` setting, although you might need to get into RT's config files to change that.

Comment: Actually, I don't want it to persist beyond the request, if at all possible.  I tried using a singleton version of RTx::FooBar::Web already once, and it works, but sharing a database handle between users isn't a great idea.

Comment: don't forget that mason has `<%cleanup>` also for that.  Set up your object in the top-level autohandler `<%init>`, stash it in your own `MasonAllowGlobals` variable, and destroy (or simply unset it) in `<%cleanup>`

Comment: Is a MasonAllowGlobals global one that's shared by all simultaneous requests?

Comment: MasonAllowGlobals just declares a particular variable in the namespace that pages run in (`HTML::Mason::Commands`, I think).  I don't think it does any initialization or cleanup.  The variable is global in each perl interpreter, which generally means per apache process;  it won't be shared between truly simultaneous requests.  If not reinitialized, it will be shared with subsequent requests run by the same interpreter, however.  If you see something weird happen every 5th page reload, look for a global variable that wasn't cleaned up.

Comment: It's very weird - I'm running in the standalone_handler, not Apache.  I stopped using $session, and it's STILL calling the DESTROY handler 56 times.

Comment: Change $RT::Logger->debug("destroy") to $RT::Logger->debug("destroy $self in pid $$") ... see if it is the same each time.